# Unchecking checkbox does nothing

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, menu

This is my menu bar
Closed:
[image]
Opened:
[image]

When window goes above a certain break point I want the menu bar to get closed.
Here is the code:
html

```
<div class="d-md-none" id="menuButton">
                <input id="responsive-menu" type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange(this)">
                <label id="menuButtonMin" for="responsive-menu">
                <svg class="ham hamRotate ham4" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="50" onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
                    <path class="line top" d="m 70,33 h -40 c 0,0 -8.5,-0.149796 -8.5,8.5 0,8.649796 8.5,8.5 8.5,8.5 h 20 v -20"></path>
                    <path class="line middle" d="m 70,50 h -40"></path>
                    <path class="line bottom" d="m 30,67 h 40 c 0,0 8.5,0.149796 8.5,-8.5 0,-8.649796 -8.5,-8.5 -8.5,-8.5 h -20 v 20"></path>
                </svg>
                </label>
            </div>
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    const check = document.getElementById('responsive-menu');
    if(check.checked){
        if (window.innerWidth > 845){
            check.checked = false;
        }
    }
})
```

Even though in console, I see that check has a False value after a break point, the menu is still open. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the checked value won't trigger the `onchange` event. You must trigger it by yourself. After `check.checked = false;` add:

```
if ("createEvent" in document) {
  var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
  check.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
else
  element.fireEvent("onchange");
```

Comment: or `handleChange(check)`

Comment: Huh that sounds interesting... But I still got an error: fireEvent is not a function

Comment: @AleksandreBregadze True, fireEvent is old stuff. I corrected it by using dispatchEvent. This way you'll use fireEvent only if your browser doesn't support event creation (I guess IE9 < )

Comment: It does work nice!

Comment: However, now I have next issue, it does not change the state of label. After I resized the button still remained in "X" shape. Maybe anything for that too?

Comment: I just tried it, the X goes away correctly.

var check = document.getElementById('responsive-menu');
    if(check.checked){
        if (window.innerWidth > 845){
            check.checked = false;
   if ("createEvent" in document) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    check.dispatchEvent(evt);
   }
   else {
    element.fireEvent("onchange");
   }
  }
    }

Make sure to alter the .checked value BEFORE triggering the event